# Avoid/override scientific notation [E] in SOAP UI Response

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, soapui

I am facing some issue while testing a web service via SOAP UI. The output field is of datatype `float`. The problem is, the value is getting converted to **scientific notation** in the response.

Example: expecting [500], actual output is [5E2].

Is there a way to avoid this other than changing the datatype of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look on [float datatype](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#float) definition:

> float is patterned after the IEEE single-precision 32-bit floating
>   point type [IEEE 754-1985]. The basic ·value space· of float consists
>   of the values **m × 2^e, where m is an integer whose absolute value is
>   less than 2^24**, and e is an integer between -149 and 104, inclusive
>   ...
>   3.2.4.1 Lexical representation
>
> float values have a lexical representation consisting of a mantissa
>   **followed, optionally, by the character "E" or "e", followed by an
>   exponent**. The exponent ·must· be an integer. The mantissa must be a
>   decimal number. The representations for exponent and mantissa must
>   follow the lexical rules for integer and decimal. **If the "E" or "e"
>   and the following exponent are omitted, an exponent value of 0 is
>   assumed.**

Basically if your number doesn't exceeds 2^24 the "E" notation is not necessary (due "E" is optional), so `500` or `5E2` are both a valid values for a xml element of this type.

Furthermore SOAPUI is not making a transform of your response, the actual output is returned by your server, if in your server code you aren't setting this value explicitly in "E" format then probably the beans which you use to implement your soap message are internally making this change, or maybe the string representation of float in your programming language... anyway the best way to do so if you don't expect to have a result with an "E" notation is to change your element type.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I understand that both the values are correct, just that the representation is different.
And NO, my java code (written in TIBCO BW) gives the output to be 500. It is just that when we invoke the webservice using SOAPUI, the value changes to 5E2.

We can't change the schema. That would be a big change for all the team involved. 
The solution for now what we came up is, "let the tester know how to convert E notation to fixed notation".

Comment: You can process the request in SOAPUI i.e with a groovy testStep to convert the value of this element to fixed notation, I think that it's not necessary but you can do it. If the answer helps you remember to accept it :).

Comment: "SOAPUI is not making a transform of your response" that is incorrect. SOAPUI DOES make a transform. Even if server response is not in scientific format, SOAPUI converts to scientific format. You may check raw server response. This is very confusing. I tried to change something on my server, although everything was OK. And I fell for that TWICE already. Please add SOAPUI option to switch off automatic conversion to scientific notation